# Jquery onLoad() - Input fields in the page loaded are not displayed correctly

Tags: jquery, jquery-load

I load dynamically a page into another.
When I load the page, all the items are taking the right CSS customizations except for the input fields. I use MDL but I've tried also with Bootstrap but the problem persists.

Displayed in page 1: [image]

Displayed in page 2: [image]

```
mainLayout.load(url, function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr) {        
    // Load the javascript associated to this html page
    if(script_path !== undefined) {
        $.getScript(script_path);
    }
});
```

I use the same code for the input field on the first page and in the loaded page.

```
<div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
    <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="input_new_tr_value" />
    <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="input_new_tr_value">{{ _('value') }}</label>
    <span class="mdl-textfield__error">{{ _('error') }}</span>
  </div>
```

Any suggestion? 
All the other elements are displayed in the right way.
I have tried also to reload the MDL js file with getScript() and the CSS file after the page 2 is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution:

Simply call "componentHandler.upgradeDom();" from the javascript file.